# Shopify - Cart.js not adding product to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Currently I'm trying to get Shopify's cart.js to add my products to cart.

It used to work perfectly but when I added variants it's started to break and for the life of me I can't get it to work. When clicking the button - it doesn't add the product to the bag at all.

```
  <form action="/cart/add" method="post" data-cart-submit>
    {% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
      <div class="w-form">
        <div class="inpost-form-option w-clearfix">
          <label class="inpost-form-label">{{ product.options.first }}</label>
          <select id="variant-select" class="inpost-quantity w-select">
                {% for variant in product.variants %}
                    {% if variant.available == true %}
                        <option value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      <button class="inpost-buy w-button" type="submit" data-cart-add="{{ variant.id }}">Add to Bag →</button>
  </form>
```

Added Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        CartJS.init({{ cart | json }});
    });
</script>
```

Console Error

> shop_events_listener-91b4691….js:1 POST
>   https://monah-uk.myshopify.com/cart/add.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It looks like there's a hard-coded variant ID trying to be added on to the button, but this is being referenced outside of the `for` loop where the `variant` variable is defined.  That would be setting data-cart-add to an empty string, so if that's how products are supposed to get to the cart nothing would ever be added.   Without the javascript, though, looking at the form is just wild mass guessing - can you please also find the javascript function that's supposed to run?  If there are any errors in the console relating to product additions, sharing those would help as well.

Comment: I've added the javascript that's being ran in my theme.liquid file to the question.

Comment: Ah! With CartJS, it looks like you're using either the Focal or Kagami theme?

Comment: The 404 (not found) error usually means that the script tried to add a variant ID that doesn't exist in your store. If you open your debugger tools to the network tab and try adding the product to the cart (helps to clear the log before you do, if there's anything showing up already), watch for the call to /cart/add.js.  In the details for that entry, you should see a request data section. At minimum, a parameter named 'id' needs to be passed, and that 'id' parameter needs to match one of the variant IDs present in your store.

Comment: To get a list of variant IDs that are on your product to be logged in your console, you can add this Liquid/javascript combo:
`{% if product %}<script>console.log({{ product.variants | map: 'id' | json }})</script>{% endif %}` - that would let you easily compare what's being passed to the AJAX endpoint with the actual variants present.

Comment: Cheers Dave - surely Shopify is generating these variants on the liquid side so they should all be present right? Is there any default scripts you could link that show an example of adding products with variants to a basket with cart.js? Documentation is fairly scarce with the data-add side of things. Or if you can edit/test my code on your end and place it into an answer.

Comment: Usually, yeah - but if something else is happening where the javascript is somehow grabbing the wrong element and passing something else weirdness would ensue.  

I took a quick look at monah-uk.myshopify.com and saw that it's currently password protected on the frontend.  Are you willing to share the frontend password (or disable the password temporarily) so I could take a look at the final rendered page?  It would help me to trace through everything going on if I could actively see how it breaks on your shop - most themes have quite a few moving parts even for simple-seeming things.

Comment: Hi Dave - the password should be switched off now. Cheers

Comment: @DaveB Any luck figuring it out? I'm still stuck on it

Comment: My apologies!  Regular job ended up being crazy busy for a few days and I didn't get a chance to check back in. Will take a look as soon as I can.